# WordPress Query: Orderby number of matched rows?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

My plugin adds a row in the wp_postmeta table whenever a post is liked:

```
meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value
27526   | 179     | liker    | 177
27527   | 182     | liker    | 343
27528   | 182     | liker    | 360
...
```

(the meta_value stores the ID of the user which liked this post).

How do I use WP_Query to query all posts, ordered by number of likes?

EDIT: This is how to do it in SQL, but I need the WP_Query equivalent.

```
SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) AS likes
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key='liker'
GROUP BY post_id
ORDER BY likes DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check Wordpress Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

You could use the parameter **orderby**: with the string **meta_key**

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'your_post_type',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'  => 'liker',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
```

Comment: That doesn't help. It just returns the results in normal chronological order.

Comment: Did you add the "order" key (ASC or DESC)?

Comment: All that would do is order them in reverse chronological order.

Answer (score 0):

I've have 3 pages...

```
ID | post_title
---+------------
6  | Home
65 | Contact   
74 | Blog
```

And then...

```
meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value
--------+---------+----------+-----------
403     | 6       | likes    | 100
454     | 65      | likes    | 140
478     | 74      | likes    | 50
```

If I run...

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'  => 'likes',
    'order'     => 'DESC'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    echo get_the_title() . "<br>";
}
```

The output is:

```
Contact
Home
Blog
```

If I run...

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'  => 'likes',
    'order'     => 'ASC'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    echo get_the_title() . "<br>";
}
```

The output is:

```
Blog
Home
Contact
```

Comment: Please read the question: `the meta_value stores the ID of the user which liked this post`. In your example, you're using the meta field to store the _number of likes_ for a post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use the SQL...

```
SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) AS likes
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key='liker'
GROUP BY post_id
ORDER BY likes DESC
```

Only IDs:

```
$your_ids = wp_list_pluck($your_sql_result, 'ID');
```

And then query like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post__in' => $your_ids,
    'orderby' => 'post__in',
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$posts = get_posts($args);
```