# Facebook get likes of profile picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, profile-picture

I want to get the likes of a profile picture in Facebook.

I just found that I can get the picture with `https://graph.facebook.com/id/picture`

And I found different FQL solutions for how to get the like count but FQL is deprecated since 2.0 and I need the ID's of the users who liked the profile picture.

Is there a way to get this?

Comment: add some codes for what u have tried.

Comment: I could not try anything because I did not found a way to get the likes of a picture. It already makes problems when I want to find a way to get the ID of a profile picture

Comment: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255949/getting-facebook-like-count)

Comment: But where do I get the ID of a profile picture?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949262/how-to-i-get-the-facebook-profile-photo-with-php). I am getting these results using a simple google search. I am not here to keep searching for u. Search things urself.

Comment: If you would read my post you know that I always know how to get the picture. The question was how to get the ID

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Provide likes List with user Id in same Facebook picture API you can check it in Facebook graph Explorer using blow sample end point

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me/photos?fields=id,created_time,album,event,from,name,link,likes

Comment: In that way I receive empty data

Comment: I have checked with my account and it is working check you have enabled all permissions or data exists or not on account

Comment: Ah my mistake with the permissions. But how can I identify the profile picture there?

Comment: you can get user profile picture using user Id example https://graph.facebook.com/{user id}/picture?type=large